# angular app, run gradle task with npm run build

Tags: angularjs, gradle, npm, package.json

I have an angular 1 app. Every time I run

```
npm run build
```

I also want to start a gradle task. Can I automatize that somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can, the command `npm run build` run the script defined in you `package.json` file.

It looks like this :

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "myAwesomeCommand; gradle myTask"   
},
```

You can change the command executed by `npm run build`. If your command is too long or if you need a script, you can also create a shell script in your current directory and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using Gradle is that it automates the commands. Thus, you can use some construction of that type (in your build.gradle file):

```
task someGradleTask {
 // ... Do something
}

task someNpmTask(type: NpmTask) {
  args = ['run', 'build']
}
```

And then make one of the tasks dependant on the other:

```
someGradleTask.dependsOn(someNpmTask)
// Moreover
someNpmTask.dependsOn(npm_install) // This task comes with the plugin below
```

You will need an NPM plugin for Gradle, which may be included like this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'
```